# How to animate hair particle growth?

Tags: animation, particles

Can't find how to animate hair particles growing. For some reason keyframes don't work on the hair length parameter.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Set the length to the longest you want the hair to be, and then keyframe the *End* factor in *Particles > Render > Timing*:

[image]

Comment: How can you do that when using a group configuration? I want to grow leaves and trees. but the end parameter disapears when using group or object.

Comment: @Jamingrone Sounds like a good candidate for a new question :) We try and keep to one question per post to keep things organized.

Comment: Odd that one is ALLOWED to animate the Hair Length in Emission section, and yet this has no effect?