# How to make hair grow for werewolf movie

Tags: hair

Ok, so super new at Blender as in I have no idea what I'm doing. I want to use Blender as a CGI tool for indie horror film. I have a werewolf movie being made and I want to learn how to 1. Create the effect of hair growing animation. 2. Attach that animation to a scene to give the effect hair is growing from the skin.  Any tips or training guides to either is much appreciated.

Comment: You can find some answers like this one here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8820/how-to-animate-hair-particle-growth. But all you need to know is more about tutorials and BSE is not the good format for that. Have a look at this kind of videos https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W5bwhwUIVjA for more information

Comment: hi, as lemon said, above, imho you need to watch, learn, experiment, master a few blender techniques: particles animation, video tracking and compositing, probably more. you can then come back here to ask specific questions about steps not working, or something you need to better understand.

Comment: Thank you so much. I know it was a super vague question, my bad, lol  ill check it out   honestly im wanting to learn the ins and outs of blender, but i was gonna try and find tutorials for beginners and work my way up. Thanks for the responses!