# How to animate particle count?

Tags: animation, particles, hair

[image]I've been trying to animate the count of the particles in a Hair particle system. It is possible in the viewport display tab to animate the amount with the percent bar, but obviously this is not getting rendered.

Since you can not animate the number in the *Emission* tab im kind of clueless on how to animate such thing. There has to be a way to reduce the particles over time right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to animate hair particle growth?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8820/how-to-animate-hair-particle-growth)

Comment: hm sadly not really. I don't want to animate the length but the count. So for example I want to have like 2000 particles on frame 100 and want them to reduce to like 200 till frame 300.

Answer (score 2):

**Animate the children.**

As intimated in question, cannot animate the hair particle count. Can however set children and animate the child count.

[image]

*Sliding the child count viewport display amount, similarly set the render*

> So for example I want to have like 2000 particles on frame 100 and
> want them to reduce to like 200 till frame 300

Example for this case, set particle count to 200, keyframe count as 10 on frame 100, and 1 on frame 300.

Comment: I tried using children but encountered some problems before. For example: adding children completely resets the rotation of the parents and u can't change the rotation of the children for some reason. Because of that it looks very uniform since the children all have the same oriention.

Comment: There is no way to rotate children seperately from their parents right?

Comment: Lots of settings to randomize. Hard to speculate without seeing other settings.  Recommend add a screenshot or sample file to your question (setting count to 1 before upload will reduce file size, can be reset after downloading).

Comment: ok I added a picture. As you can see there are like clusters of fish, meaning the children have the same orientation as the parent at the location they are generated.